# How can i manage country wise categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing an travel site in wordpress. So how can i manage country and cities? Is there any plugin or i shall develop my own plugin?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Create custom texonomy for country & cities,Whenever you add
>   something in post then select country & cities same as we select
>   category
>
> for creating custom texonomy refer [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)